# PHP <form method="post"> on multiple carousel slides

Tags: php, session, carousel

**Pretext:**

I am making a main home page with a carousel. The carousel works well. However, each slide has its own input forms. If I try and combine both forms inside of a single  tag, whenever I change slides, the page reloads to its original content. I believe this is due to the  tag holding all the inputs together, and when the carousel slide index is changed, the form values get reset.

**What I want to do**

I want to be able to have multiple  tags on one page, instead of having one encapsulating  that causes all of my selected values to get reset when changing to a different slide. Can one reference the name of a  with some sort of isset($_POST['form1'])?

When I try using multiple forms, I cannot seem to pass along any data submitted.

```
`<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li class="item1 active"></li>
                <li class="item2"></li>
            </ol>


            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                
                <div class="item active">
                  <!-- 1st input form for carousel slide -->
                  <form method="post" name="form1">
                    <!--- code for 1st carousel -->
                </div>
                  </form>

                <div class="item">
                <!-- 2nd input form on other slide -->
                 <form method="post" name="form2">
                <!-- code for 2nd slide -->
                 </form>
                </div>
             </div>

<!-- submit button that takes data selected from other carousel fields -->
     <form method="post" name="btn-submit">
          <button name="btn">Click here</button>
     </form>`
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add inputs to your forms to include any data you like.  For example:

```
<div class="item">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="form2" />
    <!-- code for 2nd slide -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Then in the server-side code you can just check `$_POST["formName"]` for the value in that `<input>`.

Comment: Thank you. So it doesn't really matter whether an input field is in <form name="form1"> or if it is <form name="form2">? It can be called the same way?

Comment: @JohnLyons: If you give the inputs the same name in each form then you can reference that one name in the server-side code.  If you give them different names then in the server-side code you'd have to check which ones are in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Again, thank you! I wasnt sure whether or not it was possible to access the name or value of a <form> tag itself